# What does "I don't trust you because you are honest" mean?

Tags: writing

When I first saw this sentense I thought it's very weird -- in my understanding of it, it means

> You are honest, so I don't trust you.

Isn't this illogical?
But someone said it actually means (why?)

> I trust you, and it isn't because you're honest.

My understanding of the implication (is that correct?):

> I don't think you're honest, but I trust you.

Similar example:

> I don't love you because who you are

Comment: I think that this can mean 1. The cause of me trusting you is not that you’re honest 2. The cause of me not trusting you is that you’re honest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what this means; it's not a standard idiom or play on words.

That said, I can offer a guess. It could be that this person is cynical; he or she believes most people are dishonest and are driven by selfish motives. So, when this person meets someone who seems genuinely honest, it arouses their suspicions.

There is a famous saying in English that goes like this:

> *If it seems to good to be true, it probably is*.

This means, if something seems too good to be true, it's probably **not** true. (This phrase often used by financial counselors cautioning investors to be wary of get-rich-quick schemes.)

So perhaps this person was saying:

> *You seem to be honest – and that is making me suspicious.
>
>   I don't trust you because you seem* **too** *honest*.

Like I said, this is how I'd interpret what the person said – but it's just a guess. You'd have to ask the person who told you to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

When I read this sentence I was expecting something to follow.

For example,

> I don't trust you because you're honest. I trust you because...

The only other meaning I can assume is that the author literally doesn't trust honest people. This seems illogical to me but it is hard to say without context.